# Laravel Passport - Как прикрутить OpenID Connect?

Tags: laravel, openid, laravel-passport

Можно ли прикрутить к Laravel Passport OpenID Connect? Как я понимаю по некому scope будет возвращать JWT токен (token_id) с некой информацией о юзере. Может кто подскажет статью, как это имплементировать в Laravel

Answer (score 7):

https://darutk.medium.com/oauth-2-0-and-openid-connect-implementation-in-laravel-authlete-4d32802ab335
Думаю Вам нужна была данная статья)
Здесь используется библиотека authlete-laravel

Comment: Ответ только со ссылкой - плохой. Ссылка может устареть. Включите в ответ важную часть, чтоб он был самодостаточным.

Comment: На эту статью я попадал, но как я понял, для реализации функционала нужно воспользоваться сторонним сервисом Authlete - это мне не подходит. Все должно быть реализовано на моих серверах